# Why my env reactjs exposed on script chunk.js

Tags: reactjs

I have reactjs app using react-app-rewire but after im build / running i saw that env was exposed on main.chunk.js, im expected that env will be encrypted or obfuscated not clearly saw as an object

this script on package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP='false' INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK='false' react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "prod": "yarn run build && serve build",
    "lint": "eslint \"./**/*.{js,jsx}\"",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.+(js|jsx|json|css|md)\"",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "doc": "jsdoc -c jsdoc.json"
  },
```

[image]

How to fix this ?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Are you asking why you can see environment variables in the DOM?

Comment: @dannyrc yeah like why my env exposed and exposed as an object, so everything is clearly visible

Comment: @Aminudin Well, what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: @AKX i expect that env will be encrypted or obfuscated, how to do that ?

Comment: What specifically are you concerned about here? I see no API keys or private data up there. Also, "im" isn't a word in English.

Comment: sorry my english so bad, Why no API or private key show on my screenshot because i not screehshot all data. Only some as a sample

Comment: @Aminudin Any encryption or obfuscation won't help in the end anyway, because the client code needs to be able to deobfuscate/decrypt the data, IOW the user can intercept it doing that.

Answer (score 2):

The environment variables are always going to be available in the DOM. React applications are single page and everything ends up in the users browser. The docs say not to store secrets in a react app.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: how to add more obfuscate or encryption on chunkjs ?

Comment: You can’t, it’s impossible to secure secrets in a react app